# Code First One to many relationship mvc c# asp.net, with many being nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create 1 to many relationship where the many is nullable?
1 Basket can have zero, 1 or many basket items.

This is what i have so far:

Basket class

```
public int Id{get;set;}
public int? QuantityOfItemInBasket { get; set; }
public double? TotalPriceOfBasket { get; set; }
public int? BasketItemId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
```

BasketItem class

```
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int BasketId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public Basket Basket { get; set; }
```

I do not know how to display the relations between the 2 classes.

Thanks

Comment: Well you probably want to start by making sure your `BasketItems` property is an array or some type of collection if it is not. I can't tell because you only posted the properties of `BasketItem`. Beyond that it's unclear what you are after. What do you mean by "display the relations" and why are you calling your classes tables? Please update your question & title to be more specific about what you're trying to do. I'm sure others will downvote or vote to close as it is now.

Comment: `public Basket Baskets { get; set; }` doesn't make sense, really. Why plural? `Basket`is not a collection. So this should be singular. Otherwise that would be confusing. If it is a typo and that _is_ in fact a collection of Basket, then you modeled a many:many not 1:many.

Comment: For tips on writing good titles, please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". You'll note that just throwing keywords into the tile is not recommended.

Comment: You could also do this in Sql Server Management Studio in 2 minutes, just sayin

Comment: This needs to be done in code first.

Comment: So this is an Entity Framework Code First issue? That model should generate the relationship you want. Or are you asking how to display the many in an MVC view?